# Multiple ROS 2 Composable Nodes in a single launch file

Tags: ros2, roslaunch, node, parallel

I have multiple composable nodes that I need to run in parallel using a single launch file, as it is a pipeline consisting of various components. Is it possible to do that in ROS 2? or should I use normal nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange!

> Is it possible to launch multiple ros2 Composable Nodes in a single launch file so that they run in parallel?

Yes, there seem to be the following two ways:

1. Multiple containers: The `LaunchDescription` takes a list of containers. So you can create more than one such container. Please see below a sample code:

   ```
   def generate_launch_description():
       """Generate launch description with multiple components."""
       container1 = ComposableNodeContainer(
               name='my_container1',
               namespace='',
               package='rclcpp_components',
               executable='component_container',
               composable_node_descriptions=[
                   ComposableNode(
                       package='composition',
                       plugin='composition::Talker1',
                       name='talker1'),
                   ComposableNode(
                       package='composition',
                       plugin='composition::Listener1',
                       name='listener1')
               ],
               output='screen',
       )
       container2 = ComposableNodeContainer(
               name='my_container2',
               namespace='',
               package='rclcpp_components',
               executable='component_container',
               composable_node_descriptions=[
                   ComposableNode(
                       package='composition',
                       plugin='composition::Talker2',
                       name='talker2'),
                   ComposableNode(
                       package='composition',
                       plugin='composition::Listener2',
                       name='listener2')
               ],
               output='screen',
       )
       return launch.LaunchDescription([container1, container2])
   ```
2. One container with multiple nodes: A container supports multiple nodes. Similar to containers, you can create more than one node. Please see below a sample code:

   ```
   def generate_launch_description():
      """Generate launch description with multiple components."""
      container = ComposableNodeContainer(
              name='my_container',
              namespace='',
              package='rclcpp_components',
              executable='component_container',
              composable_node_descriptions=[
                  ComposableNode(
                      package='composition',
                      plugin='composition::Talker',
                      name='talker'),
                  ComposableNode(
                      package='composition',
                      plugin='composition::Listener',
                      name='listener')
              ],
              output='screen',
      )
      return launch.LaunchDescription([container])
   ```

Please see an official demonstration [here](https://github.com/ros2/demos/blob/7ecb54e14e1726d543f77c798bf41e19efc1b9b4/composition/launch/composition_demo_launch.py).

Answer (score 0):

composable nodes ...
Arent you "composing" them in the same executor by using `add_node`?
It is possible to run multiple nodes in the launch file. However if you compose the nodes into a single program, you can just launch that program and all of your nodes will be running.